# Вопрос: FBSDK defaultAudience

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Доброго дня. Подскажите плз кто разбирается в вопросе  defaultAudience для FBSDK. Насколько я понял данный параметр устанавливает - кто может читать то что публикует приложение. Но получается что даже при установке FBSDKDefaultAudienceOnlyMe - на странице в FB публикуется пост с доступностью Для друзей. В чем ошибка??

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.defaultAudience = FBSDKDefaultAudienceOnlyMe;

loginButton.center = self.view.center;
loginButton.delegate = self;

self.loginButton = loginButton;
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
}
```

и собственно сам POST

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"hello", @"message", nil];
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters: dict HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {        
}];
```

Comment: ошибка скорее всего в коде

Comment: возможно, посмотрите плз - код добавил

Comment: предположу, что хотя вы и запросили доступность на onlyMe, в инумерации, друзья идут как 0, видимо вам надо передавать параметр чтоб изменять это для поста

Comment: пробовал напрямую через FBSDKLoginManager - в методе поста устанавливал defaultAudience - результат тот же

Comment: никто не может помочь?